# Create EC2 instances after they are terminated using "update" from service catalog product

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have 2 EC2 instances spawned using service catalog product provisioning. For some reasons, I have terminated them both and want to spawn new EC2 instances back (Not the terminated ones).
So I tried to update the product again from service catalog and was hoping the service catalog would create them back because the earlier instances are not present.
Product provisioning is successful and yet the EC2 instances are not created.

My product is actually a full stack comprising of some sub-stacks and one of the sub-stack actually creates the EC2 instance.

We could envision this as below -

**Full Stack**

- Sub-Stack-1
- Sub-Stack-2
- Sub-Stack-3

Question is how to get the new EC2 instances created without having to terminate the full stack.

More info on permission for these -
I have 2 roles that I have used to achieve this. 1 role is used only to provision products from service catalog. Other is admin like role that I can use to terminate the EC2 instance. I just don't want to spawn the EC2's from the admin role and use the products to provision them.

Comment: So you are saying that the CloudFormation stack deployed by AWS Service Catalog is still present, but the two instances that were terminated were originally launched from this stack? Do you have sufficient CloudFormation permissions to modify the stack that was deployed? If so you could possibly remove those instances from the template, update, then add them back to the template and update. If you cannot manage the stack in CloudFormation, you will need an Administrator's assistance to do so.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes, originally I used the full stack to get all my resources up. I had to terminate the EC2's created from one of the sub-stack. Now, I update the full stack product again to create the new EC2's. I have permission to do so with 2 different roles. 1 role can provision products from service catalog, other is the admin role that can terminate the EC2 instances. But I don't want to manually spawn new EC2 instance from this role. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: If you can use the Admin role on CloudFormation, then the above technique should work (remove from template, update, add back to template, update).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes, agree it should have worked but it isn't. I am pretty sure its nothing with the role I am using because if I could use the same role to get it running in first place, then ideally I should be able to do it again. The role to provision products suffices the requirement for provisioning the products hence I am just striking out roles as root cause of the problem. One more observation was that when I terminated the instances and tried updating the full stack (that includes the stack that creates the EC2) the resources link in the CF pointed to the terminated instances.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Oh sorry I think you misunderstood. I am not changing the source code. When I say "update" I meant, there is a provision in service catalog to update the existing product. I am using that option to get the resources back. Hope it clarifies now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS CloudFormation is not "aware" of resources changes made outside of its control. So, it currently thinks that the EC2 instances still exist, even though they have been terminated.

If you have sufficient permissions to use CloudFormation, you could:

- **Download** the CloudFormation template that was deployed by Service Catalog
- **Remove** the section that defines the EC2 instances
- **Update the stack** by providing the edited template -- this will cause CloudFormation to terminate the instances (that are already terminated)
- Edit the template and **add back the instance definitions**, then **Update the stack again** with this template (effectively the same template that was originally used to launch the stack) -- this should cause new instances to be deployed that match the original specification